# Smooth overlay on hover

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make a smooth effect overlay when I put the cursor on a image but I don't what I am doing wrong ... the overlay appearing so fast 
I don't know if my problem is in my JS or CSS

Here is my jsfiddle

css side :

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

Js side :

```
    $('.video-cover').after().stop(true, true).addClass('video-cover-hover', 1000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fkd0ewev/9/

Comment: So you want the "shaddow" to appear slower?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the `transition` property to work it needs to exist on the element *before* you make any amendments to that element. Your logic doesn't work because you're adding the `transition` rule with the class that you append to the `.video-cover`.

To fix this, amend the CSS so that the `.video-cover:after` is present when the page loads then you can use the `.video-cover-hover` class to change it's background colour, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.video').hover(function() {
    $('.video-cover').addClass('video-cover-hover');
    $(this).find('.video-cover').removeClass('video-cover-hover');
  }, function() {
    $('.video-cover').removeClass('video-cover-hover');
  });
});
```

```css
.video {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  width: 196px;
  height: 290px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 10px
}

.video-cover:after {
  content: '';
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.video-cover.video-cover-hover:after {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.video-cover img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bloc-liste-video">
  <div class="liste-video">
    <div class="video" id="video-1">
      <div class="video-cover">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/225/290/any">
      </div>
      <div class="timeago">4 days ago</div>
    </div>
    <div class="video" id="video-2">
      <div class="video-cover">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/225/290/any">
      </div>
      <div class="timeago">4 days ago</div>
    </div>
    <div class="video" id="video-3">
      <div class="video-cover">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/225/290/any">
      </div>
      <div class="timeago">4 days ago</div>
    </div>
    <div class="video" id="video-4">
      <div class="video-cover">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/225/290/any">
      </div>
      <div class="timeago">4 days ago</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```